# Puppeteer Page evaluation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, puppeteer

`` const firstp= await page.$(`a[href*="/player/ID/First_Second"]) ``
is it possible to avoid /player/ID/ while evaluating because i've `First_Second` stored as written data in JSON file so i'm passing them but i don't have ID's

Comment: did you try just `$('a[href*="First_Second"]')`?

Comment: not really but this worked! thanks in advance